# Reducing multiple mp3 bitrate

Tags: 13.04, mp3

I'm looking for a tool for Ubuntu 13.04 that can reduce the bitrate of multiple mp3 files. Does anyone happen to know such a tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reducing the bit rate will involve re-encoding, which means that you'll have to create separate output files. You could use `avconv` from the command-line:

```
avconv -i input.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k output.mp3
```

To do a whole directory of .mp3s:

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do avconv -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "${f%.*}-out.mp3"; done
```

This will create files with `-out.mp3` at the end of their names. If you want to replace your originals, you can then use `mv` to overwrite them (warning: this should be considered irreversible):

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do avconv -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "${f%.*}-out.mp3" && mv "${f%.*}-out.mp3" "$f"; done
```

It might be safer to do this in two steps:

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do avconv -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "${f%.*}-out.mp3"; done
for f in ./*-out.mp3; do mv "$f" "${f%-out.mp3}.mp3"; done
```

You can do this to files recursively (every .mp3 in the working directory and all sub-directories):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.mp3; do avconv -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "${f%.*}-out.mp3"; done
for f in ./**/*-out.mp3; do mv "$f" "${f%-out.mp3}.mp3"; done
```

Comment: How would the recursive version look like if I want to put the converted files in a different directory? Excuse my noobyness...

Answer (score 4):

`ffmpeg` is the tool I'd use, and I'd combine it with `find` to find the files I wanted converting.

```
mkdir converted
find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec ffmpeg -i  "{}" -b 100k "{}" "converted/{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Audacity.  Audacity is free, open source software for recording and editing sounds. You can use Audacity to record live audio, convert tapes and records, edit sound files, change the speed or pitch of a recording and much more.

For more info, and to download form Audacity, check out their [website](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/linux)

Or to install just click [**Audacity** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/)

<sup>Source:Audacity</sup>